Poincaré half plane model gives all imaginary sides and angles
I want to compute right triangle sides/angles from Poincaré half-plane model in hyperbolic geometry (semi-circle diameters on x-axis ).
$$ \cosh a =\frac{\cos \alpha+\cos \beta}{\sin \beta \sin \gamma}; \cdots; \cdots; \rm cyclic$$
For $ gm=\gamma=\pi/2 $ etc.
gm=Pi/2.;al=Pi/3.;b=1.0;

Eq={Cosh[a]==(Cos[al])/(Sin[bt]),Cosh[b]==(Cos[bt])/(Sin[al]),Cosh[c]==(Cos[al] Cos[bt])/(Sin[al]Sin[bt])}

NSolve[Eq,{a,c,bt}]


During evaluation of In[61]:= NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

Output is all complex.
How can I use Reduce and obtain all real triangle sides/angles?

No Reals solution. gm = Pi/2; al = Pi/3; b = 1; Eq = {Cosh[a] == (Cos[al])/(Sin[bt]), Cosh[b] == (Cos[bt])/(Sin[al]),     Cosh[c] == (Cos[al] Cos[bt])/(Sin[al] Sin[bt])}; Reduce[Eq, {a, c, bt}, Reals]

What is the role of gm? It is never used.

Used in cyclic relations,. $gm=\gamma=\pi/2$. Its sine is unity, cosine vanishes,
